# restructuring specific attribute in a migration in Room for android

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I currently have a table in my room database that uses a string value for a specific attribute. I'm looking for a way to change that value in all rows to a new object that uses a type converter to store as JSON.

specifically im trying to change an attribute called `attached_id` of type string to `list_of_attached`, where the first item in that list is a new json object that looks like `{"attached_id": "x", "type": "new item"}` where x is what used to be in the `attached_id` attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the solution may be as simple as using the SQL (or even simpler doing no changes to the data (explained below)) :-

```
UPDATE mytable SET attached_id ='{"attached_id = : '||attached_id||'", "type": "new_item"}';
```

So if the attached_id column had the value **99** then it would be changed to to **{"attached_id = : 99", "type": "new_item"}**

- [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/54c16/3)

However, if the above works then you could do nothing and just use a Dao that extracts the data such as `SELECT '{"attached_id = : '||attached_id||'", "type": "new_item"}' AS attached_id  ....`

Answer (score 1):

As per your current implementation first, you have to retrieve the JSON update the value you want to then update the table again.

I'll suggest you should make an object of your JSON and Make use of  `@Embedded` in the room. This will help you in case you want to query the table based on `attached_id`, `type` or sort using some fields present in json.

Please refer to this link to [@Embedded](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships)

Comment: my obstacle is specifically how to get and transform the data row by row, so far all my migrations have been using `database.execSQL("SOME SQL)` to add a table or a new attribute, havent found anything as to how i take one attribute from each row, do some operations on it and update it. 
as for embedded, thanks thats helpful but i still have to use type converters since its a list

Comment: then you have get the JSON and update the fields in it then update the table

Comment: im not sure how that is done inside the migration method without access to the DAO and inherent room parsers

Comment: perhaps something like `UPDATE your_table SET attached_id ='{"attached_id = : '||attached_id||'", "type": "new_item}'` ? (careful of single v double quotes) you can add a WHERE clause if not to update all rows. Somehow I don't think this is what you want. If not then you need to update the question to be quite precise i.e. an example of data to be converted and what it is to be converted to that will cover all scenarios.

Comment: @MikeT i think thats pretty much what im trying to do, im unfamiliar with the `||` operator you used in that sql statement, does it have any documentation? will it get the the row's `attached_id`? if this works my end result will be `UPDATE your_table SET attached_id ='[{"attached_id = : '||attached_id||'", "type": "new_item}]'`

Comment: `||` is concatenate so you have '[{"attached_id = : ' as a literal  concatenated with the value in the  attached_id column appended with the literal value '", "type": "new_item}]' So if the value in the attached_id column is **99** to it is changed to **[{"attached_id = : 99", "type": "new_item}]** for every row all in 1 go (or rows as per WHERE clause).

Comment: @MikeT as in, the row where its 99 become become `[{"attached_id" = : 99", "type": "new_item}]`, the one where its 100 becomes `[{"attached_id" = : 100", "type": "new_item}]`, etc? if so that is exactly what im looking for.

Comment: See (if it works) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/54c16/3 (missed the double quote at the end of new_item)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for concatenations which may lead to errors.
You can use the function [`json_object()`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jobj) from SQLite's [JSON1 extension](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) to create a **valid JSON string** and update the table:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET attached_id = json_object('attached_id', attached_id, 'type', 'new item');
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=8bc87829462d0a40834a9ea511970ab3).

Comment: As the SQlite installed with Android devices does not have the JSON1 extension installed attempting this will result in an `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such function: json_object (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR):`